# Is any simple way to prompt sequence of queries to the user using dialog in Bot framework C#?

Tags: c#, botframework

I have to prompt the following queries to the user in Dialog. how can I achieve this in BOT framework C#

is this possible using dialog chain?

`queriesCollection` typically like this. based on user answer queries to the user will vary.

```
[Serializable]
public class questions
{
      public string question {get;set;}
      public list<questions> yes;
      public list<questions> No; 
}

public class SampleQueryDialog : IDialog<SampleQueryDialogResult>
{
    list<questions> questions; { get; set; }

    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }

    public SampleQueryDialog(list<questions> questions)
    {
        Questions = questions;           
    }

    private async Task MessageReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
         // have to do somthing here..//
        context.Done<SampleQueryDialogResult>(new SSampleQueryDialogResult() { Questions = Questions, Filter = Filter });
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand this correctly, but what you need is an easier way to generate a list of questions with Bot Framework, right?

I suggest you use [**FormFlow**](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/forms.html). It can generate a list of questions using just enums.

Hope it helps!

Comment: ForFlow will not suit I guess. List<Questions> will change dynamically.it depends on previous user conversation

Answer (score 0):

Use LUIS entity recognition alongside of FormFlow, something like this:

```
[LuisIntent("SomeIntent")]
private async Task SomeIntentHandler(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    //Check if LUIS Entity count is not 0
    if(result.Entities.Count != 0)
    {
        //Pass in the recognized entities, apart from that form flow will spawn sequential questions for gathering information about your remaining entities.
       FormDialog<YourClass> yourDialog = new FormDialog<YourClass>(new YourClass(), YourClass.BuildForm, PromptOptions.PromptInStart, result.Entities);
       context.Call(yourDialog, ResumeAfterFormFlowComplete);
    }

}
```